# Open a new window (not a tab) in Chrome with all functionality(menubar Etc.) using window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

Isn't it possible to open a new full featured window in Chrome using window.open? I have tried everything using parameters, but it looks like chrome ignores the parameters :-|

It shall show a normal browser window with all the functionality that the user has enabled (status, menu, favourites, toolbar Etc.)

Btw. it is working in Firefox

Here are an example:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,dependent,width=800,height=620,left=0,top=0')
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the question and expected output? if possible!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have included an example in my question

Comment: So you want to pass those `menubar`,`toolbar` as a query parameter with that google.com? Like `http://www.google.com?menubar=yes&toolbar=yes&etc`?

Comment: The best would be not to provide any parameters, but just show a new browser window like the parent. But when I try that without parameters, it open in a tab.

Comment: That is what I am trying to ask what you are doing and what is not working?

Comment: window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank') is opening in a new tab (not window), when using parameters it opens in a new window, but there are no toolbar, status line Etc.), and I would like there to be

Comment: Just as if i would press "shift + link" in the browser

Comment: hi @PNR I am trying to do the same, did you ever get at the bottom of this?

Comment: no Unfortunately not